# php for searching in a text document with specific word

Tags: php

Its a question about php
I have a text file called data.txt and i stored data from registration in it.
Now i need to type the name in a text field of the registered student and he display the data for this student in a web page or another text document

attached to the question the first code for storing data entered from registration form

```
<?php
  $i=1;
  $fp= fopen("data.txt","a+");
  $file_content= "Data for student number".$i++."\r\n". "name:" .$_POST['fullname']."\r\n"  ."age:" .$_POST['age'] ."\r\n".  "email:"  .$_POST['email']."\r\n**********************************************************************" ;
  fwrite($fp,$file_content);  
  fclose($fp);
  echo "congratulations ! your data is stored";
?>
```

Comment: Post the code you wrote now... An see http://php.net/preg_match...

Comment: Use database for this...

Comment: I will try preg_match thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $fp= fopen("data.txt","a+");

    $i=1;    
    preg_match_all('~\w+~', $file_content, $m);
     if($m){
           $file_content= "Data for student number".$i++."\r\n".
           "name:".$_POST['fullname']."\r\n"  ."age:" .$_POST['age'] ."\r\n".  "email:"
                  .$_POST['email']."\r
                 \n**********************************************************************";
          fwrite($fp,$file_content);  
          fclose($fp);
          echo "success";
      }
      else
      {
       echo "failed";
      }
```